Copy some hash elements to another hash
Is there a more idiomatic way to create a hash with a sub-set of keys from another hash.
Currently I have:
a-subroutine('param',
  %(:$level, 
    :id(%prm<id>), :target(%prm<target>), 
    :caption(%prm<caption>), :delta(%prm<delta>)
   )
)

%prm has more keys than needed for the new hash argument.
The repeated key / %prm<key> seems ugly.

You could use
%(:$level, slip %prm<id target caption delta>:p) 


It was the :p that's the key! Equivalently: %(:$level, |(%prm<id target caption delta>:p) )
